# Looking for a list of programming or technology related "_Con" events to go to

Tags: events

I'm looking for a list of _Con events that are programming or technology related that you would suggest I go to.  For example, DefCon, or anything else for that matter.

And just to be clear, it doesn't need to have "Con" in the name to quality.

Also, I'm in southern California, and most events of this sort are in the north, so some events in the vicinity would be nice, but no locale restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Professional Developer Conference (PDC) will be in L.A. in November (17th through 19th). If you're working on any technologies using the Microsoft stack, it's a good one to attend.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course [StackOverFlow DevDays](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/) comes to mind.  Oct 16th in LA.